# Retrieve Autofac IContainer in NServiceBus

Tags: autofac, nservicebus

I was wondering if there's a way to retrieve the autofac container anytime after it's been registered. I register the module as follows (using NSB 5.0):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacConfigModule());
container = builder.Build();
busConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(c => c.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));
```

When my endpoint starts I register a listener (implementing IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops) which retrieves messages from a `WebSphereMQ`. To process these messages I had defined an interface (similar to `NServiceBus` IHandleMessages<>) which I then want to resolve and pass the deserialized message to for further processing. In order to resolve my custom interface implementation I'd like to use the container I have already registered with `NServiceBus`, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is there any way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you registered your interfaces in the container, you can use constructor injection to resolve them. Consider something like this:

```
var cfg = new BusConfiguration();
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance<IMyCustomHandler>(new MyCustomHandler());
var container = builder.Build();
cfg.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(c => c.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));
```

Then, you can inject `IMyCustomHandler` via a constructor parameter, and it should be resolved automatically by NServiceBus.

Does this help?

Comment: I ended up with something similar to your suggestion (registering a component and injecting the container as property), although I think your solution is better. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to register your own implementation of the Autofac middleware using a `ContainerDefinition`?

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers/

You could register Autofac and store the root `ILifetimeScope` as a static property to use in your application.

Something like:

```
public static class Container
{
    public static ILifetimeScope LifetimeScope { get; set; }
}

public class MyContainer : ContainerDefinition
{
    public override IContainer CreateContainer(ReadOnlySettings settings)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacConfigModule());
        Container.LifetimeScope = builder.Build();
        return Container.LifetimeScope;
    }
}
```

Then resolve your dependencies using

```
Container.LifetimeScope.Resolve<IHandleDeserializedMessages>();
```

(Completely untested sample code.)